How to read in a character datetime with a timezone offset in R?
I have a dataset containing a datetime character column, in CEST/CET time zone (Central Europe local time). The time zone offset is denoted with +01:00/+02:00 at the end. I want to convert this into POSIXct format so it can later be converted to UTC, but on the October long clock change day the additional hour from 2 am to 3 am is read in incorrectly, as the time zone offset seems to be ignored:

My goal is to make reprex$datetime_CEST_CET_converted[4] return "2023-10-29 02:00:00 CET" instead of "2023-10-29 02:00:00 CEST":

Reprex:
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

source <- data.frame(
  datetime_CEST_CET_character = c("2023-10-29 00:00+02:00", "2023-10-29 01:00+02:00", "2023-10-29 02:00+02:00",
                                  "2023-10-29 02:00+01:00", "2023-10-29 03:00+01:00", "2023-10-29 04:00+01:00")
)

reprex <- source %>%
  mutate(datetime_CEST_CET_converted = as.POSIXct(datetime_CEST_CET_character, tz = "Europe/Paris"),
         datetime_UTC = with_tz(datetime_CEST_CET_converted, tzone = "UTC"))

reprex$datetime_CEST_CET_converted[3]

reprex$datetime_CEST_CET_converted[4]

reprex$datetime_CEST_CET_converted[5] - hours(1)

I have tried adding format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M+%z" in as.POSIXct() after removing colons in the time zone offset but I get NAs as a result:


source_without_colon_in_timezone <- data.frame(
  datetime_CEST_CET_character = c("2023-10-29 00:00+0200", "2023-10-29 01:00+0200", "2023-10-29 02:00+0200",
                                  "2023-10-29 02:00+0100", "2023-10-29 03:00+0100", "2023-10-29 04:00+0100")
)

reprex_without_colon_in_timezone <- source_without_colon_in_timezone %>%
  mutate(datetime_CEST_CET_converted = as.POSIXct(datetime_CEST_CET_character, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M+%z", tz = "Europe/Paris"),
         datetime_UTC = with_tz(datetime_CEST_CET_converted, tzone = "UTC"))

reprex_without_colon_in_timezone$datetime_CEST_CET_converted[3]

reprex_without_colon_in_timezone$datetime_CEST_CET_converted[4]

reprex_without_colon_in_timezone$datetime_CEST_CET_converted[5] - hours(1)


So it seems that changing to format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%z" (essentially removing the "+") works, however if anyone knows if there is a way to read these in while keeping the colon in the time zone offsets please let me know.

Just use clock and call it a day! It has support for the +HH:MM offset-from-utc convention seen here.
Your date-time is almost in the standard RFC 3339 format, in which case you could just use date_time_parse_RFC_3339(), but the lack of seconds make it slightly more complex. Instead we parse with the more flexible sys_time_parse() and convert the results into POSIXct with as_date_time().
library(clock)

x <- c(
  "2023-10-29 00:00+02:00",
  "2023-10-29 01:00+02:00",
  "2023-10-29 02:00+02:00",
  "2023-10-29 02:00+01:00",
  "2023-10-29 03:00+01:00",
  "2023-10-29 04:00+01:00"
)

# Parse into (roughly) UTC, respecting `%Ez`, i.e. the `+HH:MM` bit
x <- sys_time_parse(
  x,
  format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%Ez",
  precision = "minute"
)
x
#> <sys_time<minute>[6]>
#> [1] "2023-10-28T22:00" "2023-10-28T23:00" "2023-10-29T00:00" "2023-10-29T01:00"
#> [5] "2023-10-29T02:00" "2023-10-29T03:00"

# Convert to POSIXct with your expected time zone
as_date_time(x, zone = "Europe/Paris")
#> [1] "2023-10-29 00:00:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 01:00:00 CEST"
#> [3] "2023-10-29 02:00:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 02:00:00 CET" 
#> [5] "2023-10-29 03:00:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 04:00:00 CET"

# Or UTC if you wanted that
as_date_time(x, zone = "UTC")
#> [1] "2023-10-28 22:00:00 UTC" "2023-10-28 23:00:00 UTC"
#> [3] "2023-10-29 00:00:00 UTC" "2023-10-29 01:00:00 UTC"
#> [5] "2023-10-29 02:00:00 UTC" "2023-10-29 03:00:00 UTC"


Write a function to do the conversion.
Below, function convert_CEST_CET_UTC uses the base R pipe so that it doesn't depend on magrittr's pipe. It first splits the input character strings by the plus sign, then separates the datetime from the timezone correction. After piping both these results to an appropriate lubridate function they are real dates and times so can be subtracted. This result is the return value.
source <- data.frame(
  datetime_CEST_CET_character = c("2023-10-29 00:00+02:00", "2023-10-29 01:00+02:00", "2023-10-29 02:00+02:00",
                                  "2023-10-29 02:00+01:00", "2023-10-29 03:00+01:00", "2023-10-29 04:00+01:00")
)

convert_CEST_CET_UTC <- function(x) {
  s <- x |> strsplit("\\+")
  sapply(s, `[[`, 2L) |> lubridate::hm() -> tz
  sapply(s, `[[`, 1L) |> lubridate::ymd_hm() -> hm
  hm - tz
}

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

source %>%
  mutate(datetime_UTC = convert_CEST_CET_UTC(datetime_CEST_CET_character))
#>   datetime_CEST_CET_character        datetime_UTC
#> 1      2023-10-29 00:00+02:00 2023-10-28 22:00:00
#> 2      2023-10-29 01:00+02:00 2023-10-28 23:00:00
#> 3      2023-10-29 02:00+02:00 2023-10-29 00:00:00
#> 4      2023-10-29 02:00+01:00 2023-10-29 01:00:00
#> 5      2023-10-29 03:00+01:00 2023-10-29 02:00:00
#> 6      2023-10-29 04:00+01:00 2023-10-29 03:00:00

Created on 2024-10-01 with reprex v2.1.0

The result doesn't look correct though: on your 1st row the UTC datetime is 2 hours later where it should be 2 hours earlier, and you get duplicate timestamps in UTC (3:00 and 4:00) where all timestamps should be unique. The manual conversion is a good idea though, I think I'll just write something to remove the colon and use the %z format.

@Vincent You are right! The times should be subtracted. Corrected now.

Found a way of resolving this by manually removing the colon in the time zone offsets, and also removing the "+" in the format argument:
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

source <- data.frame(
  datetime_CEST_CET_character = c("2023-10-29 00:00+02:00", "2023-10-29 01:00+02:00", "2023-10-29 02:00+02:00",
                                  "2023-10-29 02:00+01:00", "2023-10-29 03:00+01:00", "2023-10-29 04:00+01:00")
)

solution <- source %>%
  mutate(datetime_CEST_CET_character_without_colon = paste0(str_sub(datetime_CEST_CET_character, 1, -4), str_sub(datetime_CEST_CET_character, -2, -1))) %>%
  mutate(datetime_CEST_CET_converted = as.POSIXct(datetime_CEST_CET_character_without_colon, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%z", tz = "Europe/Paris"),
         datetime_UTC = with_tz(datetime_CEST_CET_converted, tzone = "UTC")) %>%
  select(-datetime_CEST_CET_character_without_colon)

solution$datetime_CEST_CET_converted[3]

solution$datetime_CEST_CET_converted[4]

solution$datetime_CEST_CET_converted[5] - hours(1)




The solution assumes a fixed character format, a more complex solution using regex would be required if the colon isn't always in the 3rd to last character.
